# In IIS 6, when using a UNC path for a virtual directory "using connect as" is the password secure?

Tags: security, iis-6, unc, virtual-directory

If I use a UNC share for a virtual directory, and use "Connect As" to save the username and password.

I'm presuming that these saved credentials are secure?
Is that correct? Are the credentials saved encrypted?

-thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MS don't store clear text passwords.  It'll no doubt be an NTML hash.